# Margin not working inside AppBar for Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to show some margin around the text field which is in the App bar. I want something like this.
[image]
This is the code I have

```
title: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, bottom: 50),
            child: TextField(
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
              controller: searchController,
              ,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Search',
                //filled: true,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: HexColor("#D8D8D8"),
                    width: 1,
                    style: BorderStyle.none,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(24.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Now the problem with above code is, I do not see any top and bottom margin for my TextFeild and it comes something like this.
[image]

I know I can provide a `Container` height but I do not want to hardcode that height. What should I do to add margin at the top and bottom?

Comment: what about wraping TextField with a Padding?

Comment: I tried that but no help. I see the same thing.

Comment: letterspacing? sorry i'm a newbie but it was my first thought

Answer (score 0):

This is what written in app_bar.dart regarding the title property

```
/The primary widget displayed in the app bar.
//Typically a [Text] widget that contains a description of the current
//contents of the app.
// Becomes the middle component of the [NavigationToolbar] built by this widget.
//The [title]'s width is constrained to fit within the remaining space
//between the toolbar's [leading] and [actions] widgets. Its height is
//_not_ constrained. The [title] is vertically centered and clipped to fit
//within the toolbar, whose height is [toolbarHeight]. Typically this
//isn't noticeable because a simple [Text] [title] will fit within the
//toolbar by default. On the other hand, it is noticeable when a
// widget with an intrinsic height that is greater than [toolbarHeight]
//is used as the [title]. For example, when the height of an Image used
// as the [title] exceeds [toolbarHeight], it will be centered and
// clipped (top and bottom), which may be undesirable. In cases like this
//the height of the [title] widget can be constrained. For example:

// MaterialApp(
//   home: Scaffold(
//     appBar: AppBar(
//        title: SizedBox(
//        height: toolbarHeight,
//        child: child: Image.asset(logoAsset),
//      ),
//     toolbarHeight: toolbarHeight,
//   ),
// )
```